# Show that if $E(X^2) = 0$ then $P(X=0) = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the relationship between the two above statements as part of something I'm reading in a probability book.

I'm aware of the basic definitions of $E(X^2)$ and $(X^2=0)$, i.e. that they are

$E(X^2) = \Sigma_{\omega \in \Omega} p(\omega)X^2(\omega)$

$(X^2 = 0) = X^{-1}(0) = \{\omega\in\Omega|X(\omega) = 0\}$

So if I want to show that if $E(X^2) = 0$ then $P(X=0) = 1$, I would need to somehow sum over the values of $\Omega$ to get the desired terms. However I'm not sure how to move forward from there.

Comment: Hint: fixing any $\omega\in\Omega\setminus\{0\}$, $E(X^2)\ge\omega^2p(\omega)$.

Comment: You can use [Markov's/Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) to bounded the probability that $X$ is different from zero.

Answer (score 1):

I am just a student so I hope my explanation is correct and will help you to understand better this topic.

By definition: $E[X^2]=\int_{\omega \in \Omega}^{}X^2(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=0$
By def of a measure $\mathbb{P}(\omega) \geq 0 \Rightarrow  d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \geq 0$. It is obvious too that $X(\omega)=0$ at least on a sub set of $\Omega$ with measure equal to one.

Indeed let suppose w.l.o.g that $X(\omega)=x\neq 0 \;on \; S \subset \Omega \; s.t. \; \mathbb{P}(S)>0$ with $x$ being a real number (to simplify the writting). In such a case we will have:  $\int_{\omega \in \Omega}^{}X^2(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\int_{\omega \in S}^{}X^2(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega) + \int_{\omega \in \Omega \; without \; S}^{}X^2(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\int_{\omega \in S}^{}x^2d\mathbb{P}(\omega)+0=x^2\mathbb{P}(\omega \in S)>0$

Comment: Pardon my confusion in case, but are you supposing that in general we can always choose $S$ s.t. $P(S)>0$ and $X=x$ on $S$ for some $x$? This is not true for all random variables, e.g. $X(\omega)=\omega$ on $[0,1]$ with the Borel sets and the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: You are right but as i said it is exemple to simpligy the writting, to take a simple case and make it more understable by the op.

Comment: @X0-user-0X : It is easier to use $X\leq Y\implies E[X]\leq E[Y]$ whenever random variables $X,Y$ have expectations. You can prove the Markov inequality from this, or a variant of that for all $\epsilon>0$  via $$X^2 \geq \epsilon^21_{\{X^2\geq \epsilon^2\}}$$.